# Bigcartel custom checkout page to allow orders with bank transfer

Tags: bigcartel

I'm looking for a way to do checkout on my bigcartel webshop next to the paypal checkout. I actually just want it to place the order and send the confirmation mail as setup in the (admin) notifications section. In this way I can allow orders to my customers via regular bank transfer.

I have experience in html, CSS and programming in general...

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there's no way to modify the checkout process in Big Cartel, or add another checkout option (even with heavy customization) - you'll need to use the built-in PayPal or Stripe checkout.